# Add clickable phone numbers to php mail

Tags: php, ajax

I have a website form that submits data to php the I use POST to send that data to my email. Currently when I do this the phone numbers are clickable and it would be more convenient if I can click on the phone number as it lands in the email and make the call.

Tried to add a href link for tel: but added errors to code

```
$message = '';
$message .= '<div>First Name: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']) . '</div>';
$message .= '<div>Last Name: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']) . '</div>';
$message .= '<div>Email address: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . '</div>';
$message .= '<div>Phone: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']) . '</div>';
```

Comment: What has this code got to do with AJAX

Comment: `but added errors to code`?? What error? The `htmlspecialchars` won't allow HTML to be rendered... assuming you put the HTML in the POST.. allowing it likely will open you to XSS injections.

Comment: did you add the `href` attribute to the `<div>`, or did you add an `<a>` and add the attribute to that?

Comment: @sean I added an <a> tag and added it inside the post statement

Comment: @user3783243 basically didn't compile, so what would be the best way to add in the href tel: so that it lets the numbers clickable?

Comment: @guowangcode Show the code where you actually tried to do this.  Also, "basically didn't compile" is not an error message.  What was the _actual_ error message that you received?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out..posting answer in case anyone else comes across the same problem.

```
$message .= '<div>Phone: <a href="tel:' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['number'])  . '">' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['number']) . '</a></div>';
```